# git strategy to take over changes from branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have two branches
Branch 'develop' is the branch from which nightly builds are made. So it should contain more or less working code). I made some small bugfixes after commit A
Branch 'feature' has been branched of from commit A to develop a new feature. In the middle of the work of the new feature, I realize that it would be good if it already would contain the small bugfixes.
What is the best solution to get these commits on top of my feature branch without merging that incomplete feature into 'develop'?
Shall I cherry pick? Or would it make sense to create a new branch from the top of 'develop' and use this one for merging with my feature branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `git cherry-pick` or `git checkout <feature> && git rebase <develop>`. Rebase will take the updates from develop and put them into feature. This is a useful practice to detect merge conflicts early on if you are not the only person working on the project.

Comment: I see, I still have to learn a lot :-). Rebase does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @July http://blog.founddrama.net/2013/07/git-cherry-pick/ useful to know about cherry-picking.